Spring Boot sleuth generating trace and span id as same
I am facing an issue with the sleuth distributed tracing.
I have two applications: Consumer app and provider app
When sending request from consumer app to provider app the trace and span ids are same in consumer app log however the provider app printing correctly.
Consumer App:

Provider App:

How can I fix the logger of consumer app to print correct span id rather than same as trace id?

Here is the repo https://github.com/pratapjai143/webclientdemo
